# Hash returning entire table - SAS

Tags: sas

I have a query using a hash in the data step as follows:

```
if _n_ = 1 then do;
    if 0 then 
        set TableA;
    declare hash A(dataset: "TableA");
    A.definekey ("UniqueKeyA" );
    A.definedata ("DataA" );
    A.definedone();
end;

if _n_ = 1 then do;
    if 0 then 
        set TableB;
    declare hash B(dataset: "TableB");
    B.definekey ("UniqueKeyB" );
    B.definedata ("DataB" );
    B.definedone();
end;

rcA = A.find(key:UniqueKeyA);
rcB = B.find(key:UniqueKeyB);
```

When I run the query, `TableA` returns `rcA` and the data as expected, but the hash for `TableB` for some reason brings every column from `TableB` with it. These queries look identical to me and I can't think of anything qualitatively different between the tables that would cause them to act differently, but I don't know much about SAS.

Explicitly, if my original table is

```
UniqueKeyA      UniqueKeyB
    1                A
    2                B
    3                C
```

and TableA is

```
UniqueKeyA    [...Other TableA columns...]   DataA
    1                                          53
    3                    ...                   46
```

and TableB is

```
UniqueKeyB    [...Other TableB columns...]   DataB
    B                                         .45
    C                    ...                  .22
```

my resulting table is

```
UniqueKeyA      UniqueKeyB   rcA   DataA   rcB   [...Other TableB columns...]   DataB
    1                A        0      53     21
    2                B       513            0                                     .45
    3                C        0      46     0               ...                   .22
```

This doesn't make sense to me, since the hashes seem very basic, and although theyre identical only one of them returns every column.

Please let me know if you need more information, thanks!

Also, I have another question about these same hashes entering values into the data column even though, for example, `rcA` doesn't equal 0. That question is here: [Hash find method entering values despite returning non-zero - SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387320/hash-find-method-entering-values-despite-returning-non-zero-sas)

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if 0 then 
        set TableB;
```

is where the columns come from.  This is a 'lazy' way of avoiding the uninitialized variable message that would appear from the hash creation if there isn't something technically initializing the variables before the hash.  It's fine if you are bringing every variable in, but of course if you're only bringing 2 and you have 40, you get 38 extras that you don't much want.  They're empty, but still unneeded.

Add `(keep=uniquekey datab)` to the set TableB statement and it should get rid of those other columns.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Is there any reason it might be doing this for only one of the tables?  The order of creating the hashes or calling the find method didn't change the fact that it's always TableB.

Very helpful though - I'm not much of a SAS user and I'm modifying someone else's code, I'll change it to your less lazy way.

Comment: Sometimes hash objects in SAS behave pretty weird. One time I had a problem with two hashes in the same data step. Their names were something like hname1 and hname2, so only last symbols in their names were different. And every time I run this program I received an error and not usual one, with reasonable description, but something like "out of memory.. blah-blah..Fault Occurred...Task Traceback...blah-blah". When I gave them names with more difference, everything worked ideally! So, just a thought - try to give your hashes longer names than A and B. Sounds weird, but who knows :)

Comment: That sounds awful! The actual tables in my code have more distinct names, but it's useful to know that hash objects can just act odd sometimes.

Comment: @AndyPhillips, likely you don't have any extra variables in tableA.  It would be doing that for tableA as well otherwise.

Comment: @Joe TableA actually has many columns other than the one being referenced in the hash. That's part of the reason this was so confusing - it was only happening for one table and not the other, but the statements are basically identical.

Comment: That is inconsistent with what ought to happen, then.  I doubt I could answer without sitting at your desk and seeing the exact situation; but there's no reason it shouldn't be happening for both, unless there's something else involved.