# Hash find method entering values despite returning non-zero - SAS

Tags: sas

I have a query using hashes in a data step as follows:

```
if _n_ = 1 then do;
    if 0 then 
        set TableA;
    declare hash A(dataset: "TableA");
    A.definekey ("UniqueKeyA" );
    A.definedata ("DataA" );
    A.definedone();
end;

if _n_ = 1 then do;
    if 0 then 
        set TableB;
    declare hash B(dataset: "TableB");
    B.definekey ("UniqueKeyB" );
    B.definedata ("DataB" );
    B.definedone();
end;

rcA = A.find(key:UniqueKeyA);
rcB = B.find(key:UniqueKeyB);
```

I'm under the impression that the `find` method returns 0 if the data exists, non-zero otherwise, and that if data is found it puts it into the table. However, these queries are returning non-zero values for `rcA` or `rcB` and still putting in values.

Explicitly, if my original table is

```
UniqueKeyA     UniqueKeyB
    1              A
    2              B
    3              C
    4              D
    5              E
```

and `TableA` is

```
UniqueKeyA     DataA
    1          'High'
    2          'Low'
    5          'High
```

and 'TableB is

```
UniqueKeyB     DataA
    B          'Hot'
    D          'Cold'
    E          'Warm'
```

the resulting table might be

```
UniqueKeyA     UniqueKeyB    rcA    DataA    rcB    DataB
    1              A          0     'High'    42                 
    2              B          0     'Low'     0     'Hot'             
    3              C          45    'Low'     42    'Hot'                
    4              D          45    'Low'     0     'Cold'              
    5              E          0     'High     0     'Warm'
```

I have a work around right now of

```
if rcA = 0 then DataA = DataA;
if rcA ^= 0 then DataA = "";

if rcB = 0 then DataB = DataB;
if rcB ^= 0 then DataB = "";
```

But this seems unnecessary, since I thought `find` only writes to the table if it returns 0.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Please let me know if you need any more information, thanks!

Also, I have another question about these hashes returning the entire table rather than the specified column, the question is here: [Hash returning entire table - SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386943/hash-returning-entire-table-sas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another side effect of the same thing - `if 0 then set tableA`.

Any variable that arrives in the data step through a `SET`, `MERGE`, or `UPDATE` statement will be automatically `RETAIN`ed, which means that it won't be set to missing at the start of the data step loop.  So you either need to abandon the `if 0 then set tableA/B` lines (you can replace them with a couple of `length` statements, one per variable in each hash) or do what you're doing, set them to missing manually.